# Xamarin forms, how can my command from my viewmodel reach/connect with an existing button?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my viewmodel where I have the command, that changes the value of an int. I want to bind this command to a Button.

```
public SharedViewModel()
{
    ClickCommand = new Command (() => CurrentValue = CurrentValue + 1);
}

public ICommand ClickCommand 
{
    get { return clickCommand; }
    set
    {
        clickCommand = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ClickCommand");
    }
}
```

And this is my `ContentPage` where I have a button named `click1`:

```
public MenuPage ()
{
    var ourSharedView = new SharedViewModel ();
    ourSharedView.ClickCommand; //and this is the command, I have no idea how I should connect this with my existing button below though. This 
}

void click1 (object s, EventArgs a)
{
  // how can I connect this clickbutton to my command? 
}
```

Comment: With a custom behavior for example. Don't use code behind like "Button Click" and connection this to your command. That's bad.

Comment: Hm ok. What would I do if I need to connect a certain button with a viewmodel commandvalue then? because I cannot change value with the button itself (in this partricular case as I am working iwth a propertychanged function)

Comment: Have a look at the PRISM Nuget Package. There you can bind easy commands.

Answer (score 1):

From the code behind, you can do this

```
myButton.Command = ourSharedView.ClickCommand;
```

you should remove the Button's Click handler - you do not need it if you are using a Command

Comment: can I add additional things somehow, For example if i want an image to be visible when you click on the "myButton" and the image is only reachable on your myButton page and not your viewmodel

Comment: create a  bool property in your VM.  Bind that bool to the IsVisible property of your image.  Then changing the value of the bool will cause the visibility of the image to change

Answer (score 0):

First of all creating a View Model from the View(Page) is not a good idea. Page should be created after VM is exist and use it's data.

I recomend you to read the [Data binding basics](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/), [MVVM binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/).

As for your question assume you have View Model with ICommand property, set binding of the button command in page to it:

```
public class CustomPage : ContentPage
{
    private Button btn {get;set;}

    public CustomPage()
    {
        if(btn == null)
            btn = createButtonFunction();
        btn.SetBinding<ViewModelClassName>(Button.CommandProperty, vm => vm.CommandFromViewModel)
        //btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, "CommandFromViewModel")//other way to set binding
    }

}
```

Commented line does same work as privious, use one of them.

P.S. Forget to mention that to work propertly BindingContext property of page has to be set to the View Model of this page.